# MVC 3 when is the Controller.ViewData.ModelState is populated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I am reading the MVC 3 source code to try to find when is the Controller's ModelState is set.

From the code I can see from Controller.cs that ModelState property was delegated to its ViewData's ModelStata property, like the code below:

```
    public ModelStateDictionary ModelState {
        get {
            return ViewData.ModelState;
        }
    }
```

However I can only see the ViewData.ModelState seems only populated through ValidateModel() method in Controller.cs, like the code below:

```
        protected internal void ValidateModel(object model, string prefix) {
        if (!TryValidateModel(model, prefix)) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                String.Format(
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    MvcResources.Controller_Validate_ValidationFailed,
                    model.GetType().FullName
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

in above code TryValidateModel() method would indirectly populate the Controller.ModelState like code below:

```
        foreach (ModelValidationResult validationResult in ModelValidator.GetModelValidator(metadata, ControllerContext).Validate(null)) {
            ModelState.AddModelError(DefaultModelBinder.CreateSubPropertyName(prefix, validationResult.MemberName), validationResult.Message);
        }
```

However I searched through all the source code and did not find any place that calls ValidateModel() method, and also from the access modifier, this method is protected, I wonder how this method is called by MVC 3 framework during the request processing, or ValidateModel() is only supposed to be called by user in the inherited controller class.

Comment: I wonder if this question is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210694/what-is-the-difference-between-modelerror-and-validationresult