# What is the difference between ModelError and ValidationResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, modelstate

In ASP.NET MVC there exists a **ModelState** class that contains ModelErrorCollection.  And a ModelError represents an error the occurs during model binding.

I know that **ValidationResult** is returned from ValidationAttribute.IsValid Method, and validates the specified value with respect to the current validation attribute.  I understand that we can inherit from validationAttribute and override IsValid() in order to write a custom model validation attribute.

*Example of using **ModelState***: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/performing-simple-validation-cs

*Example of using **ValidationResult***: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260177/Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-ASP-NET-MVC

How do these two work together? Or not work together?  What is the intersection?  This question is trying to understand ASP.NET MVC validation approaches better.

Why am I interested and why not just use data annotations?  The answer is, I want to better understand validation for dynamic fields in ASP.NET MVC.  In my product context, I will not have a model of pre-determined properties to attach validationAttributes to.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. From my understanding of the 2 you mentioned.

**ValidationResult** give us the ability to custom our error message linked to a property method by simply implement the `IValidatableObject` and get each model to define the `Validate` method.
So from my point of view, ValidationResult is more like a feature used for configure the conditions and results of model validation.

ModelState give us the possibility to  make our custom error from ValidationResult as part of the ModelState by doing `ModelState.AddModelError(memberName, validationResult.ErrorMessage)`

And With the combination of ValidationResult and ModelState, we can still using `if (ModelState.IsValid)` in our controller while the internal behavior already contains our custom error message and validation conditions.

Patrick had posted an detailed article regarding the validation in MVC, you can refer to [here](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/enterprise-asp-net-mvc-part-6-the-three-layers-of-validation)